# How to Include jsp views inside my principal view Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-security

Hi everyone yesterday I asked something about Spring MVC it was about the impossibility to read variables from jsp parents in jsp children injected by JavaScript.

Now, I don't know how to make this kind of process, I'm developing a web app, whith the next flow.

Login with security that redirects to user according whit it rol.

```
  protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
      boolean isUser = false;
      boolean isAdmin = false;
      boolean isSupervisor = false;

      Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
       = authentication.getAuthorities();
      for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
          if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
              isUser = true;
              break;
          } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
              isAdmin = true;
              break;
          } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_SUPERVISOR")) {
              isSupervisor = true;
              break;
          }
      }

      if (isUser) {
          return "/user";
      } else if (isAdmin) {
          return "/admin";
      } else if (isSupervisor) {
          return "/supervisor";
      } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException();
      }
  }
```

I'll focus on my admin user (the supervisor has the same page for it home, the user has a special for it)

**Controller** 
My controller my view and send some values with ModelAndView.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {
    @Autowired
    FormModelBo boFormModel;
    @Autowired
    UserBo boUser;
    @Autowired
    FormModelBo bo;
    @Autowired
    RolBo boRol;

@GetMapping
    public ModelAndView showRegistrationForm() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("adminDashboard");
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
            System.out.println(currentUserName);
            try {
                User user_complete = boUser.consultaIndividual(currentUserName);
                mav.addObject("user",user_complete);
                mav.addObject("permisos", boRol.consultaIndividual(user_complete.getRol().getRolId()));
                mav.addObject("version", VersionReader.getVersion());                   
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }else{
            System.out.println("No user");
        } 
        return mav;
    }
}
```

**JSP adminDashboard**

With the user information I got the rol info, and it had the modules for each rol, and are printed  in the div "menuZone" all element has an onclick In Jquery.

```
        <div class="row" id="principalDiv">
            <div id="menuZone">
                <c:forEach items="${user.rol.permisos}" var="permisos">


                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 iconos methodDiv" id="${permisos.permisoMetodoMap}">
                        <div>

                            <center>
                                <i class="fa <c:out value="${permisos.permisoMetodoIcono}" /> fa-5x" id="icon_${permisos.permisoMetodoMap}"></i>
                            </center>
                            <br>
                            <center>
                                <div>
                                    <c:out value="${permisos.permisoNombre}" />
                                </div>
                            </center>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>

            <div id="loadZone">
    </div>

    </div>
```

**JQuery**

It make a controller request for the section of view to be included in loadZone div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.methodDiv').click(function(event) {
        loadAsp(this);
        $('#menuZone').hide(1000);
        $('#menu').addClass("fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x");

    });

    $('#menu').click(function(event) {
        $("#loadZone").hide(1000);
        $("#menuZone").show(1000);
    })

    function loadAsp(element) {
        $.get('getInclude', {
            include : $(element).attr('id')
        }, function(responseText) {
            //alert(responseText);
            $('#loadZone').html(responseText);
            $("#loadZone").show(1000);
        });
    }

});
```

**Controller to dispatches the view**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInclude")
public class IncludesDispatcherController {

    @Autowired
    FormModelBo boConsultas;
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView giveIncludeByName(@RequestParam(value = "include", required = false) String include) {

        ModelAndView mav;

            if(include.equals("reportes")){
                System.out.println(include);        
                return getReportesView();
            }else{
                System.out.println("not "+include);
                return null;
            }
    }

    public ModelAndView getReportesView() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("includes/reportes");
        try {
            mav.addObject("consultas", boConsultas.consultaGeneral());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mav;

    }
```

**View included in loadZone div**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

        <div>
            <center>
                <legend>
<!--                //<img alt="" src="img/pen.png"> -->
<%--                    Censo M&eacute;tricas Triage <br />  --%>
                </legend>
            </center>
        </div>
        <form action="${user.rol.rolMap}/createExcel" method="POST" role="form" id="">

            <div class="form-group">

                <!-- -------------------------------------------first section--------------------------- -->
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 22px !important;">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div class="input-group ">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Fecha inicio  ${myLogged}</span> <input type="date" id="fecha_1" name="fecha_1" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div class="input-group ">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Fecha final</span> <input type="date" id="fecha_2" name="fecha_2" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generar Reporte</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>


        <div style="padding-bottom: 22px !important;">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre de médico</th>
                        <th>Número de consultas</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${consultas}" var="consultasLista">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${consultasLista[0]} ${consultasLista[1]} ${consultasLista[2]}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${consultasLista[3]}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

The model variables ("`${consultas}`") loaded at the html() moment works well but i cant access to my parents varibles ("`{$user}`").  I know that JSP is server lenguaje.

So I don't know how to do this process to mantain the flexibility that it has now. I cant load view and data information separatilly first doing a controller request and another one for the data and after populate my jsp with JQuery. but for all new option in my menu I'll need to add code for get and populate info.

How can I do this process in a good way?.